# convert dictionary array to 2D array python

Tags: python, arrays

i have a dictionary array like so  :

`myary= {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}`

i would like to convert it to a 2d array somthing like this

`in:: numpy.matrix(myary)
out::
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9`

is this even possible to do 
to convert a dictionary with keys and value to a 2D array with only values

Comment: i dont even see how this is related

Comment: Um...use `values()` on your dictionary to get a flat list of values, and then apply the accepted numpy answer from the dupe link.  What isn't clear?

Comment: Do the keys play any role here? It looks like you can just dump the values into the array.

Comment: this is just a small part of a bigger problem but to begin with i need to first convert that array in to a 2D array consisting of only values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myary= {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}
l=[x for x in myary.values()]
l.sort()
step=3
print([x for x in [l[start:start+step] for start in range(0,len(l),step)]])
#[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: i get this output
`[[{'1': 1, '3': 3, '2': 2, '5': 5, '4': 4, '7': 7, '6': 6, '9': 9, '8': 8}]]`
that is when i use` numpy.matrix(l)`

Comment: i fixed it thanks so much